# Multiple choice in PHP

Tags: php

How can i save all the inputs(question, choices, answers) in the database?
I cant save the correct answer on the database. how can i get the chosen value, which is selected through the radio button? Or is there any other?

```
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
<?php
if($numMC > 0)
    {

echo "<b>"."MULTIPLE CHOICE QUESTIONS: Enter them below followed by their correct answer."."</b>";
        echo "<br>"; 

        for ($j=1; $j<=$numMC; $j++)
            {?> 
<p><textarea name="question[<?php echo $j; ?>]" rows=3 cols=90>question[<?php echo $j; ?>]</textarea></p>
            <?php for($k=1;$k<=$numchoices;$k++)
                {
                echo $k; ?>
                <input type="radio" name="right[<?php echo $j; ?>]">
                <input type="text" name="choice[<?php echo $j; ?>][<?php echo $k; ?>]" value="choice[<?php echo $j; ?>][<?php echo $k; ?>]"><br />
<?php               }

                echo "<br>"."<br>";
            }

    } ?>

<input type="submit">
```

how will i determine which radio button is selected and how will i get the value of the radio button that is selected?

Comment: Normally, you'd use an INSERT (or maybe UPDATE) query..  but since you provide no details about your database, we can't help you.

Comment: i can add the questions and the choices. but the chosen correct answer with the use of the radio button i cant.

Comment: @MarcB how will i determine which radio button is selected and how will i get the value of the radio button that is selected?

Comment: you should really learn to accept solutions that answer your question. it will get you more answers in turn...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a table with questions like so:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| questionId | answer                    | correct |
----------------------------------------------------
| 1          | Possible answer 1a        | 0       |
----------------------------------------------------
| 1          | Possible answer 1b        | 1       |
----------------------------------------------------
| 2          | Possible answer 2a        | 1       |
----------------------------------------------------
| 2          | Possible answer 2b        | 0       |
----------------------------------------------------
```

You can build the page like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questionsTable");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
echo '<input type="radio" value="'.$row['answer'].'" name="q'.$row['id'].'"/>
}
```

You can check if the answers are correct after the form has been submitted like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $radioName = 'q'.$row['id'];
    if($row['correct'] == 1){
        //handle a correct answer here
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem with this is that the user can just look at the source to determine the correct answer.

Comment: yeah but how will i insert them to the database? since i dont know how will i determine which radio button is selected and how will i get the value of the radio button that is selected? that is why i cant insert them,

Comment: This should work. Please select an answer if one has been supplied. Thank you.